# system("clear"); not working but system("cls"); works

Tags: c

When I run this code, it throws an error saying 'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
int a=20;

printf("print a num");
scanf("%d",&a);

system("clear");

printf("%d",a);

getch();
}
```

Comment: Because it is not a command, on Windows...

Comment: On what OS are you running your program?

Comment: `conio.h` _implies_ that you'd need `cls` `:)`

Comment: You're given an error that is quite clear (sorry, no pun intended). What more did you want?

Comment: 'conio.h implies that you'd need cls' I dont understand this statement! i am new to coding.

Answer (score 4):

`system()` calls an external program. The naming and availability of external programs is highly system dependent.

Since you're using `conio.h`, use the `clrscr()` function. [ref](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/clrscr)

Comment: Hm. I see. I found a replacement for conio [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?35174-CONIO-H-alternative-for-Dev-C-IDE-Users) which includes this function.

Answer (score 1):

system("clear") is system call only in Linux Os (ie- Gcc) so u cannot mix system call with other Os.All the Os have different system call.